# Number of functions from naturals to reals (${\aleph_1}^{\aleph_0}$)

Tags: infinity, infinite-groups

The number of functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to itself is $|\mathbb{N}|^{|\mathbb{N}|}={\aleph_0}^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_1$. The number of functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to itself is $|\mathbb{R}|^{|\mathbb{R}|}={\aleph_1}^{\aleph_1}=\aleph_2$. Finally, the number of functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{N}$ is $|\mathbb{N}|^{|\mathbb{R}|}={\aleph_0}^{\aleph_1}=\aleph_2$. My question is whether the number of functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ ($|\mathbb{R}|^{|\mathbb{N}|}={\aleph_1}^{\aleph_0}$) is $\aleph_1$ or $\aleph_2$. Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Please note that I assume the generalised continuum hypothesis.

Comment: You seem to have assumed the generalised continuum hypothesis

Comment: According to [W|A](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28aleph_1%29%5E%7Baleph_0%7D), there is no known simplified form. Also, the former simplifications work only if you're assuming CH/GCH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will write $\mathfrak c = 2^{\aleph_0}$.
Compute
$$\aleph_1^{\aleph_0} \ge 2^{\aleph_0} = \mathfrak c
\\
\aleph_1^{\aleph_0} \le \mathfrak c^{\aleph_0} = \big(2^{\aleph_0}\big)^{\aleph_0}
= 2^{\aleph_0\times\aleph_0}= 2^{\aleph_0} = \mathfrak c
$$
therefore
$$
\aleph_1^{\aleph_0} = \mathfrak c
$$